# Regex Extract string with and without spaces

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I’m working on a regex extract where the line item may or may not have a space at the beginning of the string I’m looking to extract.

For example, I’m looking at the line items

```
ABC_Store:Clothes:Shirt:Blue_ABC_XYZ
ABC_Store:Clothes: Pants: Red_ABC_XYZ
```

In both scenarios, I would like to extract the third item after the colon (Shirt and Pants) but I think I am having trouble bypassing the space.

Most recently I tried `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Dimension, ‘:([^_]+):’)`
but this extracts “Clothes:Shirt” and “Clothes: Pants” rather than just Shirt and Pants.

Would definitely appreciate guidance on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` with a capture group:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Dimension, '^[^:]+:[^:]+:\s*([^:]+)')
```

### Demo